# Recursive function not working properly

Tags: java, arrays, recursion

I have an assignment to write a program that takes input w, h and raw array of values between 0 and 1 and outputs the number of "molecules" in the table. W and h are width and height of the table. Molecule is part of table that is connected with values 1 either to up or down or left or right (no diagonals).

Example input:
     4 4
     1101
     1000
     1011
     1001

Output:
3

I wrote a program that generates an array with predefined w and h and fills them randomly with values from 0 to 1 inclusive so I could test my recursive function, but I'm stuck. My function doesn't want to "turn left"/j-- and possibly i--. Any ideas?

```
package firstSoup;

import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class SoupMain {

static int width = 6;
static int height = 4;

static int[][] table;
static int moleculeCount = 0;

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Random random = new Random();       

    table = new int[height][width];

    //Fill the table with random numbers between 0 and 1 inclusive
    for(int i = 0; i < height; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < width; j++){
            table[i][j] = random.nextInt(2);
        }
    }

    //Check the the table for a possible value of 1 and turn the whole "molecule" to value of 0
    //Increment moleculeCount
    for(int i = 0; i < height; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < width; j++){
            if(table[i][j] == 1){
                turnOff(i, j);
                moleculeCount++;
            }
        }
    }
}

//Recursive function for turning only the values of 1 that are connected ("molecule") to 0
public static void turnOff(int i, int j){
    if(table[i][j] == 1){
        table[i][j] = 0;

        if(j < width-1){
        turnOff(i, j++);
        }

        if(j > 0){
        turnOff(i, j--);
        }

        if(i < height-1){
        turnOff(i++, j);
        }

        if(i > 0){
        turnOff(i--, j);
        }

    }else{
        return;
    }       
}
}
```

This is flow of the program for each first turnOff call: 
Input: 
100100
101110
110011
100011

1
000100
001110
000011
000011
2
000000
00**1**000
000000
000000
3
000000
000000
000000
000000
Output = 3

When it should look like this:
Input:
100100
101110
110011
100011

1
000100
001110
000011
000011
2
000000
000000
000000
000000
Output = 2

Comment: if the table would look like 0010  0010  0111 1111  the moleculeCount would be 3 but it was supposed to be 1

Comment: Because we don't know what you're talking about.  If `turnOff` is not working properly, please provide the input array (you'll have to get your `main` program to print it after you generate it randomly), the expected output, and the actual output.  Statements like "not working properly" and "my function doesn't want to turn left" don't provide us any information with which we can help you.

Comment: I tried to extend and clarify the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you're using postfix operators to increment/decrement your index values when you make your recursive call.  In this case `i+1` and `i++` do very different things.

`i++` and `i--` don't just evaluate to `'one more than i'` and `'one less than i'`, they also *change* the value of `i` going forward in the program.  Furthermore, they only evaluate to the incremented/decremented value *after* they have been used.

Let's take a look at what happens when your board looks like this:

```
000100
001110
000011
000011
```

Your main loop will call `turnOff(0, 3)`, like so:

```
public static void turnOff(int i, int j) {
    // i=0, j=3
    if (table[i][j] == 1) {
        table[i][j] = 0;

        if (j < width - 1) {
            turnOff(i, j++);  // calls turnOff(0,3) and sets j=4
        }

        if (j > 0) {
            turnOff(i, j--); // calls turnOff(0,4) and sets j=3
        }

        //etc
```

This screws up your bounds checking and makes many out-of-order and redundant calls, which breaks your algorithm.  What you *want* to do is call the recursive method on each cell adjacent to the current one:

```
public static void turnOff(int i, int j) {
    // i=0, j=3
    if (table[i][j] == 1) {
        table[i][j] = 0;

        if (j < width - 1) {
            turnOff(i, j+1);  // calls turnOff(0,4)
        }

        if (j > 0) {
            turnOff(i, j-1);  // calls turnOff(0,2)
        }

        //etc
```

In the long run, I cannot stress enough how important it is to learn to use a debugger.  Your brain "sees" what you think you've written, not what you've actually written.  Until you set a watch on a variable and see it do something unexpected, it's often very difficult to identify where your program is going astray.

Comment: Thank you very much for taking your time and explaining the problem. I was using debugger but to be honest, I still get lost in larger stacks. I was also taking my sweet time with figuring out the solution and I've noticed my brain starts to slack after a few hours or so of "intense" staring in to the editor :) And thank you for restoring my faith in stack overflow. Sometimes I get the feeling people get pissed if they have to take more than 5 minutes of their life to answer a question to get some rep point.